# Fail2Ban with DDWRT or router

Tags: linux, router, firmware, fail2ban

How can I use fail2ban with DDWRT or a router?

I love using fail2ban, but there is no info about using fail2ban in a linux base ddwrt / optware / entware and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to add to the WIKI, you might wanna add in:

## Fail2Ban is not easy, but can be done cooly!

Right now, I use git but you can download the latest as well.

```
opkg install git git-http bash ca-bundle ca-certificates python  

cd /opt 
git clone https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban.git 
cd fail2ban 
mkdir -p /opt/log
mkdir -p /opt/run/fail2ban
mkdir -p /opt/lib/fail2ban/
cp /opt/fail2ban/config/jail.conf /opt/fail2ban/config/jail.local
cp /opt/fail2ban/config/fail2ban.conf /opt/fail2ban/config/fail2ban.local
```

## Required modification for `fail2ban.local`

```
logtarget = /opt/log/fail2ban.log
socket = /opt/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
pidfile = /opt/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
dbfile = /opt/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3
```

## Setup

There will be an info that /etc/fail2ban is not writable, but it is not a problems

```
cd /opt/fail2ban 
setup.py install
```

## Init script `/opt/etc/init.d/fail2ban`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/opt/bin/python /opt/fail2ban/bin/fail2ban-server -c /opt/fail2ban/config/ $1
```

## Startup command in like DDWRT

```
/opt/etc/init.d/fail2ban start
```

## Shutdown command in like DDWRT command

/opt/etc/init.d/fail2ban stop

by Patrik aka `p3x-robot / p3x / corifeus`

Comment: i use with python2 and it works